# iOS, retrieve image and would retain or keep original URL link when adopt the HTML format into NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uitextview

for ios, objective-c, here would like load an html file(aa.html) into UITextView, but i would like to keep the url of the image when doing the transform, for reload purpose, but it seems to shorten the link. Eager for the help. Many thanks.
The following is the code:

```
// aa.html is my local html format file
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aa" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                               initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                               options: @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                          NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                               documentAttributes: nil
                                               error: nil
                                               ];
// retrieve image here
[attributedString enumerateAttribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName
                             inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length])
                             options:0
                          usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop)
 {
     // when it is NSTextAttachment(kind of image)
     if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSTextAttachment class]])
     {
         NSTextAttachment *attachment = (NSTextAttachment *)value;
         //the complete url is shorten after Encoding
         // the attachment here can only show "bb.jpg", but what i expect is the full url like: https://attach.mobile01.com/attach/201811/bb.jpg


     }
 }];
```

Comment: You should load the HTML in Webview. that is the best way.

Comment: but i need to insert local gallery photo into the uitextview later-on, so i need to custom the inputView, which seems not to be allowed

Comment: Can you tell me what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would load a html source file and adopt it into my UITextView, which is editable with both words and local gallery photo( all insert from custom inputview). After edited, upload the uitextview context with html format again. So i can not lose the url attribute value when adopting into uitextview~~